# PHP Array to return a URL

Tags: php

I am trying to return a specific iframe URL depending ont he input of a specific number of zip codes.

Example- zip code x returns url x
zip code y returns url y

I have a list of several zip codes per URL. The URL purpose is to redirect to a specific (3rd party) page based on the location input from the user.

Here is what I have so far:

```
    <?php
$userzip = $_POST['ZipCode'];
    echo $userzip;
$array = array(
     '22942' => 'URL1',
     '22701' => 'URL2');
    // print_r($array);
    foreach( $array as $key => $value ){
    // echo "Output of Key=>Value pair:\r\n";
    // echo $key . "->" . $value . "\r\n";
    // echo "Testing $key...\r\n\r\n";
    if(preg_match('/23456/',$key)){
        echo "Service exists in: $value\r\n";
        break;
    } else {
        echo "No Match for $key.\r\n\r\n";
    }
}

?>
```

So, my first mistake is that only the zip code entered is returned for the moment. I can comment that out but left it in to show my thinking. Help?

Comment: Rolled back your answer. You should always keep your original question. This way people can see your original question, and *why* people answered as they did. You can add an edit, or ask a question about an answer in a comment under the answer

Comment: I didnt know how to paste the new edits

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your request correctly then this code should work:

```
<?php

$userzip = $_POST['ZipCode'];

echo $userzip;

$array = array(
     '22942' => 'URL1',
     '22701' => 'URL2');
    // print_r($array);
    foreach( $array as $key => $value ){
    // echo "Output of Key=>Value pair:\r\n";
    // echo $key . "->" . $value . "\r\n";
    // echo "Testing $key...\r\n\r\n";
    if(strstr($key, $userzip)) {
        echo "Service exists in: $value\r\n";
        break;
    } else {
        echo "No Match for $key.\r\n\r\n";
    }
}

?>
```

To actually handle the redirect then after `echo "Service exists in: $value\r\n";` you can use one of these options:

```
header("Location: " . $value);
```

Or if you want to use the iFrame approach you have mentioned in the comment then:

```
echo '<iframe src="'.$value.'" border="0" frameborder="0" style="width:500px; height:700px;"></iframe>';
```

Comment: Hey Chris, thanks for helping me out. I get this form the code you sent: 22942Service exists in: URL1  which is on the right track.

Comment: Great. Is there anything else or has this answered the question? I wasn't 100% sure that I had fully understood your question

Comment: it' almost there but i need a little more tweaking... so this form is basically in the background and if someone put in 22942 for example, I need for the user to be redirected to "<iframe src="http://sites.towercoverage.com/Default.aspx?mcid=16142&Acct=6499"  border="0" frameborder="0" style="width:500px; height:700px;"></iframe>"

Comment: I have updated my answer. There may be a better way but it's difficult to say without seeing all your code.

Comment: This answer uses a loop where you do not need one. Dont use loops for simple stuff.

Comment: <?php

$userzip = $_POST['ZipCode'];

echo $userzip;

$array = array(
     '22942' => 'Gordonsville,
     '22701' => 'URL2');
      foreach( $array as $key => $value ){
          if(strstr($key, $userzip)) {
        echo "Service exists in: $value\n\n";
        break;
    } else {
        echo "No Match for $key.\n\n\n\n";
  echo '<iframe src="'.$value.'" border="0" frameborder="0" style="width:500px; height:700px;"></iframe>';
    }
}

?>

Comment: Im trying to add the current version of the code but this is the first time Ive tried this. Not getting it right just yet :(

Answer (score 0):

You should try to avoid loops as much as possible. You can easily check if a key/value exists in an array with [`isset`](http://php.net/isset):

```
$userzip = $_POST['ZipCode'];
echo $userzip;

if( isset($zipcodesA[$userzip]) ){
    echo "Service exists in A: ".$array[$userzip]."\n";
} elseif( isset($zipcodesB[$userzip]) ){
    echo "Service exists in B: ".$array[$userzip]."\n";
}elseif( isset($zipcodesC[$userzip]) ){
    echo "Service exists in C: ".$array[$userzip]."\n";
} else {
    echo "No Match for $userzip.\n\n";
}
```

In this case, you have no need to check *every value in the array*, just if one specific exists.

Comment: Interesting, thank you Martijn. I'm looking into this as well as Chris' answer

Comment: Chris' answer might work, but it loops through *all the values* only to check if it exists. Loops in PHP are resource expensive. `isset()` is one of the most lightweight functions there exist in PHP and does *exactly* want you want. Apart from that, the readability is a whole lot better. Code should also be readable.

Comment: "$userzip = $_POST['ZipCode']; echo $userzip; if( isset($array[$userzip]) ){ echo "Service exists in: ".$array[$userzip]."\n"; } else { echo "No Match for $userzip.\n\n"; }" got that when I tried it

Comment: You wrap it in `<?php` right? otherwise it's not PHP. Some thinking is allowed ;)

Comment: After I wrapped it in php, I got "22942No Match for 22942. "

Comment: Ok let me re-state more clearly if possible (sorry for the confusion):

Comment: Given a zip code entry, if its zip code 12345, or 23456 then it goes to "<iframe src="http://sites.towercoverage.com/Default.aspx?mcid=16142&Acct=6499"  border="0" frameborder="0" style="width:500px; height:700px;"></iframe>" and then have that repeat 3 more times to alolow for the other 3 sets of possible zip code entries

Comment: TYou can now check in three arrays. If this isnt what you mean, edit your answer and provide examples.

Comment: Ok I see what you mean about 3 arrays, I just need to have a fully laid out example from which I can emulate the rest. If zip code 22942 is entered, it needs to redirect user to this url: <iframe src="http://sites.towercoverage.com/Default.aspx?mcid=16142&Acct=6499"  border="0" frameborder="0" style="width:500px; height:700px;"></iframe> ... Can you put the redirect to that url in the code so I can see what that is supposed to look like, please?